# Increasing value of Javascript Variables?

Tags: variables, mootools

im processing link click events  with mootools. 
in my html i have  a links with the id of this pattern:   toggle_NUMBER   e.g. toggle_1
now i get the id with this peace of code

```
var id = $(this.get('id').replace(togglePrefix,emptyPrefix));
```

my problem starts now:
i remove the prefix this way

```
var togglePrefix = 'toggle_', boxPrefix = 'page_', emptyPrefix = '';
```

so what should remain is a simple number like 1, 2 or  3.
now i tried  to increase  this number by one

```
var id_new = parseInt(id)+1;
```

but this didnt work and i have no clue how  to change it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable "id" is an object, because return value of $ function in mootools (and jQuery) is an object.

Try this:

```
var id_new = $(this).get('id').replace(togglePrefix, emptyPrefix) + 1;
```

Comment: returns me 11 not 2 as intented.

Comment: but this worked:
var id_new = parseInt($(this).get('id').replace(togglePrefix, emptyPrefix)) + 1;

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $(this).next() before you went hacking into the ID?

Comment: no  sorry   i  heard  for it  sometimes  but i can hardly find any  documentation about  .next() on mootools site

Comment: that's because it's Element.getNext[1] in MooTools. Alas, I'm sure there's a better way to tackle your whole issue by refactoring the code.

[1]: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element:getNext